# RAILS - Submit form to the same page and display query results

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to display dynamical charts based on user's choises.
I want to let the user choose options from several select menus filled by data coming from db tables.
When the user submit the page, I want to fire a query in order to get the data to build my charts with.

I'm new to Rails and I cannot figure out how to do this.

I've made a new model, setting it to "Abstract" (as I don't need to write anything to the db, just display query results) but I don't know which action I have to use (index, new etc.).

I hope I had correctly explained the problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your problem in your views you can use `form_tag` with `remote: true` option and `url` set to your index action. Add your business logic to return chart data in index action. `remote: true` option will fire request asynchronously. In your views use returned data to display chart.